# Append HTML to default folder directory using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, append

### How can I modify the default folder directory in Apache?

I want to modify the directory(which shows when a folder's `index.ext` or `default.ext` pages aren't found) by appending some HTML to it, is this possible in `.htaccess`? If not, what're the alternatives?

[image: index directory]

Comment: not possible, create your own default index file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place this .htaccess in your document root:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /listing.php
```

This will search for a index.html or index.php in the accessed folder. If both aren't existing it calls listing php from the document root (note the `/` in front) as fallback. Use this file to code the directory listing on your own. This way you have fully customized index pages.

Comment: Nice! What would i put in `listing.php` if i want to put something after the directory listings, a link for instance.

Comment: You need to code the listing for yourself with php. Using `glob()` or `readdir()` for example. Then output the obtained file information + your additional html